# Neural Network Is Taking 1000 Epochs Just To Solve XOR

Tags: neural-network, xor

My Neural Network takes 1000 epochs just to solve XOR and when I increase number of neurons loss increases and it doesnt work.

Also before when I was using np.random.rand it did'nt work with a learning rate less than 1.

```
import numpy as np

input = np.array([[0, 1] ,[1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 0]])
labels = np.array([[1], [1], [0], [0]])

np.random.seed(0)

class NN:
    def __init__(self):
        self.layers = []
    def add(self, layer):
        self.layers.append(layer)
    def loss(self, layer):
        self.loss = layer
    def predict(self, input):
        output = input
        for layer in self.layers:
            output = layer.forward(output)
        return output
    def train(self, input, labels):
        prediction = self.predict(input)
        loss = self.loss.forward(prediction, labels)
        gradient = self.loss.back() * 0.1
        for layer in self.layers[::-1]:
            gradient = layer.back(gradient)
        return loss
```

Dense Layer

```
class Dense:
    def __init__(self, input_size, output_size):
        self.weights = np.random.randn(input_size, output_size) - 0.5
        self.bias = np.random.randn(1, output_size) - 0.5
    def forward(self, input):
        self.input = input
        output = np.dot(input, self.weights) + self.bias
        return output
    def back(self, gradient):
        gradientW = np.dot(self.input.T, gradient)
        self.weights -= gradientW
        self.bias -= np.mean(gradient)
        return np.dot(gradient, self.weights.T)
```

Sigmoid

```
class Sigmoid:
    def forward(self, input):
        output = 1 / (1+np.exp(-input))
        self.output = output
        return output
    def back(self, gradient):
        output = self.output * (1 - self.output)
        gradient *= output
        return gradient
```

I am using Mean Squaresd Error

```
class MSE:
    def forward(self, input, labels):
        self.input = input
        self.labels = labels
        return np.mean((labels - input)**2)
    def back(self):
        output = 2 * (self.input - self.labels)
        return output
```

Calling the Class

```
N = NN()
N.add(Dense(2, 10))
N.add(Sigmoid())
N.add(Dense(10, 1))
N.add(Sigmoid())
N.loss(MSE())
```

Training

```
for i in range(1000):
    loss = (N.train(input, labels))
    if i%99==0:
        print(loss)

print(N.predict(input))
```

Edit: I Tried this and now it works with 100 epochs. I needed an additional layer to increase neurons why? I tried to train it on AND but it doesnt work.

```
N = NN()
N.add(Dense(2, 50))
N.add(Sigmoid())
N.add(Dense(50, 1000))
N.add(Sigmoid())
N.add(Dense(1000, 50))
N.add(Sigmoid())
N.add(Dense(50, 1))
N.add(Sigmoid())
N.loss(MSE())
```